# Fitting of the Lévy triple

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes, statistical-inference, levy-processes

Given a Lévy process and its triplet $(\mu,\Sigma,\nu)$ i.e. the triplet such that for each $t\ge 0$
$ X(t) = bt + W_A(t) + \int_{|x|<1} x \tilde N (t, dx) + \int_{|x|\ge 1} x N(t,dx)$
where $\tilde N = N-\nu$.

Does anyone know if it is possible to fit the Lévy triplet directly from the data?

Comment: Really, I don't know. Nevertheless, it might be some similarity with the method of fitting involving integral equations, as described in the paper : http://fr.scribd.com/doc/14674814/Regressions-et-equations-integrales